# Null Exception if process is already running

Tags: c#, .net

Hello  the below code is working, but if one of the programs is already open it will throw a null exception for the GetProcessByName line.

How can I track the process correctly if the process is alrdy running?

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "SomeFolder\\Folder\\Output");

string fname = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, Title);  //<--- Title property will be like text.xlsx, test.docx etc)

    Process sproc = Process.Start(fname);

    string pname = sproc.ProcessName;

    Process info = Process.GetProcessesByName(pname).FirstOrDefault();

    using (Process eProcess = info)

    {
       eProcess.MainWindowTitle.Contains(fname);

       eProcess.WaitForExit();

       //Do Other Stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `sproc` instead of `info`?

To answer the question, [GetProcessesByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) returns the friendly name of the process (i.e. usually no extension). So this should work

```
string fName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pname);
Process info = Process.GetProcessesByName(fName).FirstOrDefault();
```

But as mentioned earlier, if that is your full code, there's no need to create an `info` variable because you're needlessly finding the same process that is already being stored in `sproc`.

Comment: Updated the orig. question with path and fname, thanks for the reply

Comment: I don't think your update make any difference? Just change `fname` from my answer to another name, as you've already got `fname` in your updated code.